Razor class library - view from library is not used for controller in host
Host application is ASP.NET Core MVC. Host application has SampleController and Index action. Index action has no View file in host project.
Structure:
- Host application
├── Controllers
│   └── SampleController
└── Views
    └── Sample

Razor class library in my project works as plugin. They are loaded dynamically at startup of host application. e.g. SamplePlugin project has Views/Sample/Index.cshtml.
Structure:
- Razor class library (SamplePlugin)
└── Views
    └── Sample
        └── Index.cshtml

If I define controller inside SamplePlugin that works by default. However I would like to avoid copy of duplicate controllers between plugins.
Goal: as there can be many implementations to third-party, I have controller in host that is using interface service. Razor class library should contain View files and interface implementation for specific service.
EDIT: Based on https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38373#issuecomment-1449717787 solution was to remove Content  lines from .csproj

If you want share the solution for other folks, I suggest you could create a demo provide a more  details answer.

Solution is in first post since it was under review and I couldnt asnwer my question. Was solved before it went live automatically after 24h

There is bug in csproj that suddently removes Views from compilation (inside plugin project)
Resolution is to follow guide by https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38373#issuecomment-1449717787
to remove Content lines from .csproj file
